# Error performing functions inside a GeoFire and Firebase query

Tags: android, arraylist, firebase, geofire

I am querying nearby locations using Firebase and the results are correct when I do a systemPrint. But when I tried to create a new Location item and put it in a globally declared arrayList then loop through the ArrayList to print it. It doesn't print. I tried something similar with a hashset where I declare a global hashset and tried adding the id and geolocation to it, then loop through it, it didn't print.

This is the printout when I do a systemPrint:

```
03-05 21:42:16.225 12604-12604/? I/System.out: aa6b6c55-40da-416e-bbc0-626f10d2db80 51.02878131 -114.13542057
03-05 21:42:16.262 12604-12604/? I/System.out: 1f682c8b-be9a-4310-aa92-216f041f0547 51.02933723 -114.13514678
03-05 21:42:16.262 12604-12604/? I/System.out: 707a5af3-8fa0-4f69-b88f-593a0acd3ee8 51.02933723 -114.13514678
```

I set this arrayList globally

```
List<Locations> locationList;


in onCreate(){
......
locationList = new ArrayList<>();
......
}



 geoFire = new GeoFire(new Firebase("https://xyz.firebaseio.com/locations/"));

        GeoLocation center = new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
 final HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, 5);
        geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyEntered(String username, GeoLocation location) {

                System.out.println(username + location.latitude + location.longitude);

                Locations eachLocation = new Locations();
                eachLocation.setId(username);
                eachLocation.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.latitude));
                eachLocation.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.longitude));

                locationList.add(eachLocation);


//
//                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onKeyExited(String username) {
                usersNearby.remove(username);
                // additional code, like removing a pin from the map
                // and removing any Firebase listener for this user
            }
            @Override
            public void onKeyMoved(String s, GeoLocation geoLocation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryReady() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onGeoQueryError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

    for (Locations x: locationList){
        Log.i("eachLocation", x.getId() + x.getLatitude() + x.getLongitude());
    }
System.out.println(hs);
```

This is my Locations class

```
public class Locations {
    String id;
    String latitude;
    String longitude;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
```

}

*****UPDATE - I am also noticing another pattern where I can not perform function inside another Firebase query****

I declared a global userCountry variable, userCountry, and then I run a query to 
obtain the user's country that is saved. Inside the function, it logs fine. But when i try to set the country value to userCountry, and log it outside of the query, my app crashes and errors out on a NullPointerException. I need to set userCountry globally so I can feed it into another query as a parameter.

```
String userCountry;


 ref = new Firebase("https://xyzChat.firebaseio.com/users/" + intent.getStringExtra("userId") + "/country");

    Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("country");

        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Log.i("userCountry", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue()));
                userCountry = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            }
```

Log.i("secondUserCountry", userCountry);

Comment: You mean to say the for loop `for (Locations x: locationList){` is not printing the items?

Comment: @Abdullah, yes it's the loop that is not printing.

Comment: You get the data in `onKeyEntered` which will be called after sometime and you print the list immediately after you set the `GeoQueryEventListener`. The call is asynchronous.

Comment: @Abdullah in onKeyEntered, the call should be called immediately per the doc - https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java, if "The location of a key now matches the query criteria." And since the locations I have stored are in my search criteria, it should be called right away. When I did systemPrint, it printed. But it won't load into my ArrayList.

Comment: Do you check logcat..the item in the for loop should be printed in the logcat..

Comment: @SanketKumarMali As mentioned, SystemPrint prints fine (I updated the post to show) with the results I expected. It's just that the results won't load into the arrayList, and print after.

Comment: locationList = new ArrayList<>(); I think it should be, locationList = new ArrayList<Locations>();

Answer (score 1):

Events are fired asynchronously in GeoFire. So at the time you print out the `locationList` it will still be empty. You will need to wait until `onGeoQueryReady` is called until all elements have been added. If you move the logging code into there, it should print all locations. Note that `onGeoQueryReady` is called every time you update the query.

Answer (score -1):

Override **toString ()** method in "Location" class..
Add this code in "Location" class..

```
 @override
public String toString ()
{
    Return "id:"+this.getId ()+",  Latitude:"+this.getLatitude ()+",  Langitude:"+this.getLangitude ()+"\n";
}
```

Now change your code..Remove the loop..instead of this code

```
Log.i("eachLocation", x.getId() + x.getLatitude() + x.getLongitude());
```

Just use..

```
Log.i ("eachLocation",hs);
```

Now your code should works fine...