# Retrieving data using GeoQuery

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

So, I used this library called GeoFire (src: https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) to get a post from user within a certain distance. In my code, I made a method like this:

```
private HashMap<String, GeoLocation> getPostAroundUser(DatabaseReference rootRef) {
    final HashMap<String, GeoLocation> postHashMapLocation = new HashMap<String, GeoLocation>();
    DatabaseReference refPostGeo = rootRef.child("geo").child("posts");
    final GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(refPostGeo);
    GeoQuery geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(mLatitude, mLongitude), 3);
    geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Post with key: " + key + " was added to hash with location (lat, long): (" + location.latitude + ", " + location.longitude + ")");
            postHashMapLocation.put(key, location);
            Log.i(TAG, "number of entry after added " + postHashMapLocation.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Post with key: " + key + " was removed");
            postHashMapLocation.remove(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {
            Log.i(TAG, "number of entry onGeoQueryReady " + postHashMapLocation.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    Log.i(TAG, "total entry in function: " + postHashMapLocation.size()); //postHashMapLocation.size() returns 0
    return postHashMapLocation;
}
```

But this method returns an empty `HashMap`, so I added some log to see what is going on, here is the log:

```
02-21 18:09:32.609 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: total entry in function: 0
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -Kd7DPzEZHSdGHqfbmna was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1459048, 106.692038)
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 1
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -Kd7DULwW01S9-haorm9 was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1459048, 106.692038)
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 2
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -Kd7Dt6uvs50qddJHxiA was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1459048, 106.692038)
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 3
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -Kd7EOF41MijwSfrxpX1 was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1459048, 106.692038)
02-21 18:09:32.839 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 4
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -KdB3mJvB0K6nSCtNnoL was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1333898, 106.6861029)
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 5
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -KdB3r13H7y3jiovlLdi was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1333898, 106.6861029)
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 6
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: Post with key: -KdB58ArIOFKHrfEnYpr was added to hash with location (lat, long): (-6.1335054, 106.6910521)
02-21 18:09:32.849 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry after added 7
02-21 18:09:32.869 15115-15115/com.example.company.app I/ExampleActivity: number of entry onGeoQueryReady 7
```

It turns out the log I put before returning the `HashMap` fired up before the log inside the `geoQuery`. That's why the method return an empty `HashMap`

So, my question is, how do I get the `HashMap` from inside the `onKeyEntered` to be returned by this method? Because as you can see from the log, the `HashMap` was updated inside `onKeyPressed` but I can't retrieve it to the outside of `geoQuery`.

Note: I found a similar problem here [Error performing functions inside a GeoFire and Firebase query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821951/error-performing-functions-inside-a-geofire-and-firebase-query), but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

Geofire callbacks (such as `onKeyEntered`) are invoked asynchronously....more than likely after you've returned from your`getPostAroundUser` method.  You'll need to structure your app accordingly.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: It will really depend on your application and what you want to do with the data.  A common example might be to update your `RecyerlView` adapter or perhaps google map from those callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

the reason your hashmap is empty, is because you have set it as a final variable and thus initialized it as an empty set. final means it is unmuttable and thus can not change. So when you initialized it, it was empty and thus will stay empty

Comment: my suggestion is to add postHashMapLocation as a global variable instead of local